# Why is Firefox removing / ignoring hidden input values from an HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms, firefox, hidden-field

I have an HTML form that uses hidden inputs to manage behavior in the PHP processing script.

In browser testing I found that the form works perfectly in Chrome and IE, but there's a problem with Firefox.

The Firefox browser (using 39.0) removes hidden input values. They just completely disappear leaving only `value=""`. This in turn messes up my PHP.

I've searched high and wide for information about this issue but have found nothing.

Why is Firefox removing (or ignoring) hidden input values in my HTML form?

**In Original File**
[image]

**In Chrome Developer Tools**
[image]

**In Firefox Inspector**
[image]

**UPDATE** (based on comments posted)

*Browser Tests*. The form has been tested across all major browser both desktop and mobile versions. The form works perfectly across all browsers (including Firefox mobile), but fails to fully function in Firefox desktop (39.0) because the hidden input values are removed.

**UPDATE 2**

Re-starting and re-installing Firefox has failed to fix the problem.

**UPDATE 3**

Have removed all client side scripting and checked HTML validation (no errors). Problem persists.

**UPDATE 4**

This seems to be an issue related to the way Firefox caches data and handles POST requests.

When I "Clear All History" (including cookies, cache, etc.) the form works as intended... ONCE.

In all subsequent submissions the `value` attribute has an empty value, and no data is passed to PHP, until I "Clear All History" again.

This doesn't happen in other browsers.

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt that FireFox really removes input field values just like that. As you say yourself: there is no evidence for that on the internet. So maybe you should look for other explanations... Maybe there is some client side scripting that alters the markup? Maybe there is some server side scripting that reacts on the browser identification? The fact that the order of properties is altered as well suggests that the content has been re-created by some processing step inbetween

Comment: How could that be "messing up your php?"  php is scripted server side; it operates independent of any browser interpretation.  those tools are irrelevant.

Comment: @nomistic it could be messing up PHP because it is expecting the field to exist. When a field is empty, it is not sent to the server at all. I can see this being a problem.

Comment: I checked on 39 - everything is working properly. This is all the code? You can reproduce this behavior in `jsfiddle.net`?

Comment: @Anonymous sorry to differ, but the interpretation of this code is client side and would happen AFTER the code was sent to the browser.   As arkascha states, likely there is something going on from some client-side tools.  It could not be php.

Comment: Client side scripting that alters the mark-up only in Firefox? It's the exact same form being tested across browsers. Works fine across all desktop browsers _except Firefox_, and all mobile browsers _including Firefox_.

Comment: @nomistic No one is saying PHP causes the issue, he's saying that the value being empty is causing PHP issues when the form is submitted.

Comment: @nomistic, the hidden value in the html is sent to the PHP script to manage behavior. When the value is empty, nothing is sent, and it messes up my script. Anonymous is correct.

Comment: just out of curiosity, I tested this out, and am using the same version of firefox.  I am unable to duplicate this.  The value appears.  Note, if it appears in the view source, it shouldn't be a problem either.

Comment: Note with any client-side scripting, there can be browser variations to how it is interpreted

Comment: Again, I'm not sure whey this problem is confined to this one browser. Maybe I need to uninstall and download from scratch. If I find the solution I'll post it here. Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: good luck.  However I am suspicious that there is something here that you are not telling us.   If there really is a problem, it should not go away (bugs never fix themselves, the circumstances only change).   If there's some javascript (or something else) that is causing this problem, it could easily appear again for another user

Comment: @nomistic, it does appear in Firefox view source, it just doesn't appear in Firefox Inspector, and browser is not acknowledging the value.

Comment: Tried loading FF in safe mode (i.e. with addons disabled)?

Comment: @nomistic, I coded this form from scratch. HTML, CSS, jQuery (AJAX) and PHP. There is nothing in any of the code that targets any single browser. It's definitely an issue with Firefox (because the form works everywhere else).

Comment: see if it works without the jquery (AJAX).  I'm guessing something is happening there.  browser variations make me crazy

Comment: Something like this could potentially be caused by some type of HTML error such as overlapping closing tags. Default behavior in most browsers could be different in a newer browser.

Comment: @MaxHaaksman, form validates without errors.

Comment: @nomistic, all JavaScript disabled. Problem persists.

Comment: if you can include the full html form in your question, I'll take a look

Comment: I had the same problem when I had a value with spaces at the beginning. Trimming the value before concatenating with the rest of the HTML solved the problem for me.

So yes this could be caused by server side scripting. You send the same HTML to different browsers and they act differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. No client side script used. I nested the hidden field in a div and then all worked.

This worked:

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" value="<?=($_SESSION['CSRF-TOKEN'] ?? 'token')?>"name="_token">
</div>
```

This replicated exact behavior described in post:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?=($_SESSION['CSRF-TOKEN'] ?? 'token')?>"name="_token">
```

Either variant above worked on Chrome. Issue only appeared on desktop Firefox 63.0.1 (64-bit).

Update (2018-11-15) Actually in my case the issue was that the HTML was malformed (there was no space before the name attribute). It appears that Chrome was tolerant of this and Firefox less so. Firefox submitted the value once and then not again unless cache was cleared. Correcting the HTML corrected this quirky behavior experienced with Firefox. Corrected HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" value="<?=($_SESSION['CSRF-TOKEN'] ?? 'token')?>" name="_token">
```