# form_with trying to post instead of patch

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-5, hidden-field

While editing an instance of a model:

It's working fine in `google chrome` and `safari` , however in `Firefox` the hidden _method value displays as a string of random numbers and letters  while in `chrome` it's shows as method `PATCH`.

Please check attached link for more detail.

https://ibb.co/3BbsHj9
https://ibb.co/kKcTrJF

Comment: Hi Mark, there's a similar issue in PHP but it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495222/why-is-firefox-removing-ignoring-hidden-input-values-from-an-html-form

Comment: This is due to the autocomplete bug in firefox https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37864